# Evaluate an expression in AngularJs template

Tags: angularjs

I have a little problem with an AngularJs template
I would like to evaluate something like this :

```
<span>{{myObject[prop]}}</span>
```

When I have a controller such like this :

```
$scope.myObject = { code: "1", value: "foo" };
$scope.prop = 'value';
```

In fact, I would like to dynamically retrieve a property of an object in a template. Here I would like to bind "myObject.value".

Thanks for your help !

Comment: [Your example works fine....](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/6058/)

Comment: Thanks. Yes, it works fine. Too much beers for me... ;-)

Answer (score 3):

you can do this in this

```
<span>{{prop}}</span>

$scope.myObject = { code: "1", value: "foo" };
$scope.prop=$scope.myObject.value;
```

Comment: myObject[0] is undefined, myObject is an object not an array :/

Comment: Wawy you can check this one actually i trie it in console.

Answer (score 0):

```
{{ myObject[prop] }}
```

...

```
$scope.myObject = angular.fromJson( $templateCache.get('mytemplate') )
$scope.prop = 'a_prop_from_template_object';
```